# Индекс находился вне границ массива, с#

Tags: c#, массивы

```
int[] max = new int[m];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
     {
         max[m] = max[m] + C[i, j];
     }
 }
 Console.WriteLine($"max = {max[m]}");
```

Ошибку выдает на строчке: `max[m] = max[m] + C[i, j]`.

В чем ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: потому что в массиве отсчет элементов начинается с 0, а значит последний в массиве элемент будет иметь номер `m-1`, ошибка возникает в строке `max [m] = max [m] + C[i, j];` нужно переделать `max [m-1] = max [m-1] + C[i, j];`

Comment: @Monomax поняла, спасибо большое)

Comment: Думаю, у вас там должно быть `max[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас массив имеет размеры `m`:

```
int[] max = new int[m];
```

По умолчанию индексация ведется с нуля, т.е. ваш массив имеет ячейки с индексами `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `m-2`, `m-1`.

Вы же пытаетесь обратиться к ячейке с индексом `m` — `max[m]`, ее не существует, отсюда ошибка.